# Make looping dynamic for more than 1000 data

Tags: vba, excel

The function code I have developed below is working fine, and the formula I am using is `=adj(cell1,cell2)`.

Now I would like to make it a dynamic function for any `j` value so that I can use it for any data in my worksheet ( some data has `j value = 500` ).

The formulas execution as shown in the picture
[image]

```
Public Function adj(x As String, y As String) As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim t, z As String
    Sheet1.Select
    With Sheet1
        j = x
        z = Chr(10)
        i = 1

        If j = 3 Then

            t = Evaluate(y & (i) & "))") & z & _
                Evaluate(y & (i + 1) & "))") & z & _
                Evaluate(y & (i + 2) & "))")

        ElseIf j = 2 Then

            t = Evaluate(y & (i) & "))") & z & _
                Evaluate(y & (i + 1) & "))")

        ElseIf j = 1 Then

            t = Evaluate(y & (i) & "))")

        End If

        adj = t
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right direction but there are a couple of things that I would like to point out:

- Try to avoid .Select
- No need to reference sheet1 as the code will automatically reference the active worksheet
- Rather than doing an IF statement for each value, use a For loop to move through all the values

Code:

```
Public Function adj(x As String, y As String) As String

Dim j As Long
Dim t As String

    t = ""
    j = x
        For k = 1 To j
            If k<j Then
            t = t & Evaluate(y & (k) & "))") & Chr(10)
            Else 
            t = t & Evaluate(y & (k) & "))")
            End If
        Next k
    adj = t

End Function
```

Comment: Many..Many thanks for your help!!!, really appreciate it. This works perfectly and will defiantly save aloooooooooot of my time!!!
just for my knowledge, why t is marked t="" in the first place ?

Comment: would you please edit it so that the last t without chr(10) at the end, thank you for your support!

Comment: I got it :) , I have updated the code as follow:

  `  t = ""
    j = x
        For k = 1 To j - 1
            t = Chr(10) & Evaluate(y & (k) & "))") & t
        Next k
        
    adj = Right(t, Len(t) - 1)'

Comment: T="" in the beginning, because you need to ensure that T equals nothing to avoid having an extra extra string in your function.